# How to handle an External OAuth2 auth with Spring Boot + Angular

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a Spring Boot application as a backend and an Angular 6 front end. They work great separately, and I used [this guide](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-2-angular-7-example) as a starting point. I am now getting to the point where I want to use external OAuth to authenticate my users to get access to some of their WoW Character data.

I have a decent idea on how to restrict access to the backend with OAuth as Spring Security makes that pretty easy. What I am struggling with, is if my users are authenticated + authorized to access character A, how do I handle this on the front end **and** the back end?

Since Angular is handling the routing for the HTML pages, and those HTML pages call my back end, I'm not sure how to extend the authorization to Angular. I can show code, but I think this is more of a conceptual problem than a code problem.

Comment: What OAuth provider do you plan to use? What Angular OAuth library are you using , if any at all? You have JWT or just bare tokens? Which OAuth flow do you plan to use? Using one of the concepts is not a big deal, but it depends a bit on your details.

Comment: I'm basically just authenticating off of Blizzard's OAuth. I don't have anything picked out on the Angular side, so I guess that's what I am asking... Do I need a separate OAuth library for Angular and for Spring?

Comment: Yes, of course. Angular has no idea what Spring is :)

Anyway.  I can try to show an example, wait for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your frontend code some OAuth love. E.g [this](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) is a good library (I use it), but YMMW.

Now, the long answer:

OAuth spec defines several different "flows", and the one commonly used for client-side applications is the *implicit flow*. What that means is, if you wanna go vanilla, implement this yourself, you need to do something like this:

1. On page load: check for the URL state. If a token & data are found, store them in sessionStorage.
2. If no token in the URL, check for sessionStorage for tokens.
3. Every HTTP request to *your* backend, you append the accessToken in the headers.
4. For log in/log out, you need to redirect the user to OAuth server with a specifically crafted URL and params.

Now the longer answer:

1. On page load, check if you have some state in, say, sessionStorage. Like, a saved `accessToken` or something like that. (Not exactly, but read on).
2. If yes, you *may* want to validate this token at the OAuth server (sometimes you'd also save the expiration timestamp in storage, you can check that one too).
3. On any Http request to backend, you append this token (`accessToken` or sometimes `id_token`, or it may be a jwt, bearer, whatever, let's just say token) to the **headers** of every request. Usually it's something like a `Authentication` header, with the value `Bearer ${ token }`.

   - Backend can now check this token, and if valid, return your data, if invalid or missing, it returns 401. (It can also do a redirect to the auth server, but please don't do that).
4. If there is *no* token on page load, you might indicate this to the user. Like, ask them to log in.
5. This login button would *redirect the user to OAuth login page*. They go away from your page. It's a specially crafted URL, giving your app data, like `http://server/auth/your-app-name?clientId=your-client-id&redirectUrl=http://your-angular-page/where-you-wanna-land`. How exactly this looks like, depends from server to server, implementation to implementation.

   - Now the user landed on their login page, gives his username/password/permissions etc (or if they're already logged in there, mgiht redirect back right away). After they log in and give your app permission, the auth server *redirects the user back*.
6. Now you're back at step 1. But instead of checking for `sessionStorage`, you first want to check the URL.
   Because the url will look like: `http://your-angular-page/your-route?accessToken=<some_token>&...` and other similar things. Now you read the accessToken and store it locally and you're done.

Comment: Wow! This helps out a lot. I'll give all this info a shot, thank you!!

Comment: I had a quick question @Zlatko, the Battle.Net/Blizzard OAuth API returns an auth code. Is this the code I'd use to pass between the front end/back end?

Comment: Hmm, depends on what they use - might be that that's the access token you need. Alternatively the code is now used to get an actual token. Don't ask, I know it's complicated. That is why it is best to simply use something like the library that I've linked to, handles all the crap for you.

Comment: So it actually looks like it's a bit more confusing. It seems that the angular-oauth2-oidc library [doesn't handle such a flow](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/19). Blizzard also [doesn't recommend using the code flow](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/19288410020#post-5) on the client due to client ID and secret sharing. However, now I'm lost as to how the server is going to tell the client to show the Battle.Net login page, if its the server invoking the OAuth API?

Comment: Nonono, the lib supports implicit flow. Which is where you just redir3ect the user to blizard to auth, and get back a token.